Why is my "And" function returning a value of True when the conditions aren't met
print("Welcome to Python Pizza Deliveries!")
size = input("What size pizza do you want? S, M or L: ")
pepperoni = input("Do you want pepperoni on your pizza? Y or N: ")
extra_cheese = input("Do you want extra cheese? Y or N: ")
bill = 0
s_price = 15
m_price = 20
l_price = 25
pepperoni_price = 0
extra_cheese_price = 1
easy_check = size+pepperoni+extra_cheese
print (easy_check)


if easy_check[1] and easy_check[2] == "y" or "Y":
    print(f"Your total bill with p and ec is${bill+pepperoni_price+extra_cheese_price}.")
elif easy_check[1] == "y"or"Y":
    print(f"Your total bill with p is ${bill+pepperoni_price}.")
elif easy_check[2] == "y" or "Y":
    print(f"Your total bill is with ec ${bill+extra_cheese_price}.")
else:
    print(f"your total bill is ${s_price}.")


I am currently learning to code, and building a simple Calculator for a delivery service.
My problem is with the first if statement, as per the function, my intention is check that both statements, that is, easy_check [1] and [2] should both be == to "y" if easy_check is("SYY"), however, when I run the code and set the value of easy_check to ("SNN"), it returns a value of True thereby ending the process and giving an INACCURATE RESULT. I tried debugging with THONY, but Kept seeing it evaluating the value to True when it shouldn't
enter image description here
As per the photo, I added "with p and ec" to the print function below the function and saw that it evaluated the value as true. I can think of no other reason as to why it would Hold a value of true, I indexed correctly. I tried enclosing them in brackets but that didn't help;
I also tried using "IS" but it gave an error as expected.
Kindly Help!

Separately, please don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.

the linked question provides you an answer of how to compare to multiple options, but in your case you should convert the answer to lowercase and just do a single comparison easy_check[1].lower() == "y"
